# Why is the wilcox.test results overlapping when I try to plot a graph?

Tags: r, graph, statistics

I'm trying to get statistics on my faceted graph, but the output of the wilcoxon test are overlapped like this:

[image]

The code I am using is this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = count, x = time, group = time)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(1, 250)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(cluster), scales = "fixed")+
  stat_compare_means(method= "wilcox.test")
 labs(y = "Clone count", x = "Time point")
```

And my data looks like this:

```
structure(list(time = c("Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", 
"Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 1", "Day 1", 
"Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", 
"Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", 
"Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", 
"Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", 
"Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2"), count = c(1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 59L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 54L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 207L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 1L), cluster = c("C", 
"C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "D", "D", 
"D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "C", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also, how would I add significance bars to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may helps by specifying `comparisons`.

```
my_comparisons <- list(c("Day 0", "Day 1"), c("Day 1", "Day 2"), c("Day 0", "Day 2"))
ggplot(df1, aes(y = count, x = time)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_y_log10() +
  stat_compare_means(method= "wilcox.test", comparisons = my_comparisons)  +
  facet_wrap(.~(cluster), scales = "fixed")+
  labs(y = "Clone count", x = "Time point") +
  ylim(c(0,400))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But why are there no comparisons between Day0 and Day2?

Comment: @Chinemerem That's because of typos...I'm sorry... You may change `ylim`'s number.